# Python script to select the already opened excel file

Tags: python, excel

I have a nice python script for refreshing  of an excel file. What it does is it opens the excel file, refreshes it, saves and then closes.

But now I want to change this -
I want to open the excel file(s) manually, and then the python script should choose the particular already opened excel file(s) on the taskbar, should refresh it and save it but not close it. The action should repeat again in 1 hour.

Can anyone help me.

Here is my current script

```
import win32com.client as win32
import time
xlapp = win32.DispatchEx('Excel.Application')

wb = xlapp.Workbooks.Open('Excel path')
xlapp.visible = True
wb.RefreshAll()
time.sleep(10)
wb.Save()
wb.Close()
xlapp.Quit()
```

Comment: what does 'refresh' mean, and why need refresh?

Comment: So I have this excel file which is an dynamic file taken from the CRM 365. So with the "refresh all" button in the data tab of the excel I get new datas from CRM. 
But after the new update of CRM, the normal refresh doesn't work anymore.  There is a new add-in button in the data tab called "Refresh from dynamics 365" which connects to my CRM 365 and then "refresh all", but if I close the excel file and open again I need to manually click Refresh from dynamics 365 again.

Comment: Earlier to this CRM update the above script was working just fine, but now there is this manual task of "refresh from dynamics 365". So my thought was to do this task manually for all the excel file and keep it open so that python can select the excel file and do the refresh and save but not close.  So that the connection towards my CRM remains as it is, once closed its lost.

Comment: Any help please.?

Comment: the automation process(as with many other ui automation process) is not stable. i think a CRM(especially developed by big vendors sucha as Microsoft) should have a function to export/download latest data directly, then you can do stuffs based on the latest data.

Comment: True, the direct method is either by manual refresh from dynamics and refresh all or using dataflow using Power Automate. I don't want to go in that way for now.
I found out a script that can make me select the file. Now I don't know how to link the script to the above where it can make the refresh. 
`import pygetwindow as gw 
 print(gw.getAllTitles()) 
handle = gw.getWindowsWithTitle('Excel name')[0]
handle.activate() 
handle.maximize()`